# Hacer Login con usuario o con Email con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, login

mi consulta es saber si en la siguiente function se puede implementar que el usuario pueda iniciar sesión usando tanto el usuario como el email la funcion que tengo es el siguiente:

```
function login(){
        global $db, $username, $errors;

        // grap form values
        $username = e($_POST['username']);
        //$email = e($_POST['email']);
        $password = e($_POST['password']);

        // make sure form is filled properly
        if (empty($username)) {
            array_push($errors, "Usuario es Requerido");
        }
        if (empty($password)) {
            array_push($errors, "Contraseña es Requerida");
        }

        // attempt login if no errors on form
        if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $password = md5($password);

            $query = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1");
            $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { // user found
                // check if user is admin or user
                $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
                if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'admin') {

                    $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                    $_SESSION['success']  = "Usted se ha conectado";
                    header('location: admin/home.php');       
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
                    $_SESSION['success']  = "Usted se ha conectado";

                    header('location: index.php');
                }
            }else {
                array_push($errors, "Combinación incorrecta de nombre de usuario/contraseña");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¡Saludos, Jose!

Realmente no sé si habrá otra manera de hacerlo, pero yo lo he logrado hacer de la siguiente manera:

Reescribe tu consulta de SQL y agregar la columna `email` de tu tabla `users`:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE (username='$username' OR email='$username') AND password='$password'
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Perfecto Gracias..!